# there + semantic verb

Tags: verbs, subjects, there-is, existential-constructions

What semantic verbs are used with *there* besides the verb *to be*?

I'm looking for the cases when *there* is used as a formal subject.
For example in:

- *There came a knock*
- *There comes a point in life*

Comment: *There she blows!*, *There but for the grace of God go I*.

Comment: Your *there* is the locative *there*. The OP's is the meaningless *there* usually used in existential sentences as a Subject. Your there is an Adjunct, not a Subject.

Comment: @Araucaria Well, there you have it!

Comment: @Araucaria: There **seem** to be restrictions on which verbs can be used like this (for example, I don't think it's possible with, say, *to stop*). Might it be that *be, come, seem* and other acceptable verbs all relate to the same essential quality of "existence" (or *appearing* to exist)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed so! Just what I wrote in my answer ;-) There's that and there's also 'appearing' and being in a location too.

Comment: @Araucaria: What is the difference between *there* in *there were no cookies* and *there comes a time*? They both seem to be rather less deictic than the average *there*.

Comment: @Cerb: I don't think there *is* a difference. In the case of the cookies, for example, you could say *There are no cookies **there***, which to my mind proves that the first instance of ***there*** has nothing to do with "locative adverbs".

Comment: @Cerberus The general concensus is that in your examples, the word *there*, although historically derived from locative *there*, has become bleached of its locative meaning, and been reanalysed as a different part of speech within native speakers' grammar. So they'd agree that it has no deictic meaning at all. There are a couple of people who doubt that this word has *no* meaning at all - but they are in a minority.

Comment: @Cerberus So as FF says above, they would see both the *there*'s in your sentences as being the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OK so how about this, then?: *Eurydice descended into the Netherworld. She tried to hide by the Styx, but eventually there came a hound there to drive her off to Tartarus.*

Comment: @Araucaria: OK so how would you analyse this?: *there were sitting at the gate two enormous hounds, with five heads between them*.

Comment: @Cerberus: It's as Araucaria says below. Presumably, ***there*** originally had only the "locative" sense, but it's gradually lost this in the construction under consideration. With verbs very closely related to TO BE in semantic terms, we can often use it in sentences with no apparent locative element, but if you check out more circumlocutory forms such as *there runs a river, there winds a road*, they almost always explicitly include some kind of locative element.

Comment: ...here's a really weird one in *The Illustrated London News (1933)*. [*...further forward (not seen in the photograph) **there plays a band** of trumpets and horns in the traditional German manner.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22there+plays+a+band+of%22)

Answer (score 10):

These types of sentences are referred to as presentational constructions. They consist exclusively of intransitive verbs:

- *There ate John a lion. (ungrammatical, transitive verb)

The verbs that allow this kind of usage quite often take no Complement at all. If we have a very big, often indefinite, Subject and there is no Complement of the verb, such sentences will sound very odd if the Subject is in its normal position:

- A day when he could no longer bear to speak to her at all came. (awkward)
- There came a day when he could no longer bear to speak to her at all. (better)

This is because of information packaging constraints. We like to put the important and new information at the end of the sentence. Using *there* as the Subject here, displaces the 'notional' subject to the end of the sentence, where it achieves its full effect.

Semantically, many of the verbs which allow such constructions designate existence, coming into view, or being in a specific location.

An example with a location:

- There stood in the corner a small cluster of ornaments.

An example regarding coming into view:

- There appeared in the doorway a tall dark stranger.

An example regarding existence:

- There exists no known solution to this problem.

Here is an entry from the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Huddleston & Pullum 2002, on presentational constructions:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Araucaria, great answer! "The time has come when we have to face the enemy" vs "There has come the time when we have to face the enemy". Which one sounds more grammatical and natural?

Comment: Your example with "A day when he could no longer bear to speak to her at all came" is cheating a bit, since (as Rathony implies) the normal way to say it is: "A day came when he could no longer bear to speak to her at all."

Comment: @ruakh Hi, ruakh. I didn't mean to imply "A day when he could no longer bear to speak to her at all came" has an issue. IMHO, when we use a construction with the dummy *there*, it is not very natural to use the definite article *the*. That's what I am now researching and I am seeking an opinion of Araucaria about that. Maybe my comment was not clear enough.

Comment: @ruakh Actually, what you'll find is that both existential constructions  and extraposition from noun phrase movement are strategies used to solve this problem. See [my post here on extraposition from NP movement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253496/meaning-of-and-the-day-came-when/253550#253550) and also a [small one here too](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254521/word-order-for-subordinate-questions/254577#254577). That example with the relative clause shunted to the end is a HNPS sentence.

Comment: @Rathony Exactly so! Existential and presentational constructions can only very rarely be used with definite NPs. CaGEL mention some exceptions to this rule [here, top of page 1403](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/16/items/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language.pdf#page=1417&zoom=auto,-242,851). But that would indeed seem to be why your sentence using the extraposed relative clause is preferable to the rather awkward existential one with the definite article. CaGEL would definitely agree with you :)

Comment: Hi @ruakh (continued ...) Although as mentioned in my post and as proposed by Rathony, existentials / presentationals are preferred for sentences with indefinite noun phrases and don't work well if the subject has a definite article.